How do I tell React to useRef inside a custom Hook after layout rerenders?
So this is sort of complicated.
I have a React component, that the client has asked if we can make one part of the page fullscreen (like a YouTube Fullscreen Video). I have a little button in the corner of the component that the user can use to toggle this part of the component full screen.
The problem I'm having is the component needs data which it pulls in from another source and it is passed in via a React Content Object. It needs this data before the page loads.
So I figured it would me sense to make a custom hook for this.
My hook looks like this.
useFullScreen.tsx
import * as React from "react";

type useFullScreenProps = {
    ref: React.MutableRefObject<null | HTMLDivElement>;
};

const useFullScreen = ({ref} : useFullScreenProps) => {

    
    const [isFullScreen, setIsFullScreen] = React.useState(false);
  
    const enterFullScreen = () => {
        if (ref.current) {
            ref.current.requestFullscreen();
        }
    };

    const exitFullScreen = () => {
        if (document.fullscreenElement) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        }
    };

    const toggleFullScreen = () => {
        isFullScreen ? exitFullScreen() : enterFullScreen();
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const handleFullscreenChange = () => {
            setIsFullScreen(document.fullscreenElement !== null);
        };

        document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", handleFullscreenChange);

        return () => document.removeEventListener("fullscreenchange", handleFullscreenChange);
    }, []);


    return [isFullScreen, toggleFullScreen];

};

export default useFullScreen;


The viewer component calls it like so.
ViewerComponent.tsx
import useFullScreen from "./Common/useFullScreen";

const ViewerComponent = () => {
    let viewerRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const [isFullScreen, toggleFullScreen] = useFullScreen(viewerRef as any);
    const viewData = useClientObject<ExamData>(React.useContext(ClientContext), "viewer_data");


    if (viewData === undefined || Object.keys(viewData).length === 0) {
        return <h4> Loading page</h4>
    }

 return (

   <div id="view-workspace" ref={viewerRef}>

     <button onClick={toggleFullScreen as () => void}>
      {isFullScreen ? 'Exit Fullscreen' : 'Enter Fullscreen'}
     </button> 

     <div> {/* Rest of the page goes here */} </div>

   <div>
)

};


So the problem is that I can't figure out how to pass the ref to hook so it can use it.
Since my page uses data that it needs before it can render the whole component. It never sees the viewerRef DOM Element.
I've tried everything, with useEffect I can correctly get the reference to the dom element, but then I don't know how to call the hook again?
React.useEffect(()=>{
 console.log(viewerRef.current) <-- this works, but now how do I tell the hook about it
},
[examData])



Why are you doing viewerRef as any?

useFullScreenProps is an object with a ref property, so use useFullScreen({ ref: viewerRef });. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Suggestion: Use { ref: viewerRef } as the parameter when passing to useFullScreen.
Here is the modified code:
const [isFullScreen, toggleFullScreen] = useFullScreen({ ref: viewerRef });

The main change here is to keep the div that viewerRef points to (i.e., <div id="view-workspace" ref={viewerRef}>) in the DOM regardless of whether the data has finished loading. This way, even if the data hasn't loaded during the initial render, viewerRef.current can still point to this div element.
It is not recommended to cast viewerRef to any before passing it to useFullScreen.
Casting to any weakens type checking, which may result in not being able to promptly detect errors when incorrect parameters are passed.
For example, if useFullScreen expects an object as a parameter but uses any to bypass type checking, TypeScript will not throw an error.
If useFullScreen requires more parameters in the future, this direct passing method is also not easily extensible.
